# Session Filters are not supported on Get and Load method of Nhibernate?

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

I need to apply filters on Get/Load method which Nhibernate doesn't support. What are some techniques to apply filters on get/load.
I am aware about one where I can modified value in DefaultLoadEventListener. Can anyone suggest some better techniques?

Answer (score 0):

You could use interceptors to achieve this. Following code apply the filter condition when it tries to fetch the object.

Important section of the code is, overridden OnPrepareStatement method where it alters the fetch SQL to filter based on given condition. Text based matching is rather crude method of doing this, but I hope you get the idea.

```
public class TenantInterceptor : EmptyInterceptor
    {
        private ISession _session;

        public override void SetSession(ISession session)
        {
            _session = session;
            base.SetSession(session);
        }

        public override object GetEntity(string entityName, object id)
        {
            object entity = base.GetEntity(entityName, id);

            if (entity != null && entity.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(User)))
            {
                var filter = _session.GetEnabledFilter("Tenant") as FilterImpl;

                if (filter != null)
                {
                    var filterValue = filter.Parameters["name"];
                    var user = entity as User;
                    if (!user.Tenant.Equals(filterValue))
                        return null;
                }
            }
            return entity;
        }


        public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
        {
            if (sql.ToString().EndsWith("FROM \"User\" user0_ WHERE user0_.Id=?"))
            {
                var filter = _session.GetEnabledFilter("Tenant") as FilterImpl;
                if (filter != null)
                {
                    var filterValue = filter.Parameters["name"];
                    sql = sql.Append(string.Format(" And user0_.Tenant = '{0}'",filterValue));    
                }
            }
            return base.OnPrepareStatement(sql);
        }
    }
```

Comment: But this filter is not being applied when we have collection inside a entity. For example I have active filter for roles. I have user entity inside which a collection of role is there. If some role becomes inactive than also when I get/load user all roles comes from db including inactive one.

Comment: Even this is the case i think still onpreparestatment is fired, and you can tinker the SQL to load only ehat you want.